# How to render partial view inside a view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET MVC. I have to render Partial View inside a View. My Partial view has a model and an action method *MangeUsersInRole*. Anyways, I tried Html.RenderPartial, Html.Partial. One webpage, I'm experiencing an exception:

[image: Exception]

Heres my approach:
View:

```
@model UserRole

<form method="post" action="/HKRole/AddUserToRole">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Id" name="roleId" class="form-control" hidden />

    </div>
</form>
@Html.Partial("ManageUsersInRole");
```

Partial View:

```
@model List<ManageUsersInRole>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <td>@Model[i].UserName</td>
                <td>@Model[i].UserEmail</td>

            }
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you read `exception` properly you will get idea anyway, you are passing `UserRole` in your `partial view` and in `partial view` you have mentioned `List<ManageUsersInRole>` which will obviously create an error. so change model either in Partial view or send `List<ManageUsersInRole>` in `partial view`.

Answer (score 1):

The partial view `model` uses whichever model type was used in its parent view in this case `UserRole` instead of `List<ManageUsersInRole>` unless you explicitly pass the model value as parameter with the expected type you explicitly express in the partial view in this case `List<ManageUsersInRole>` One approach to handle multiple model types for a single view or single + partial view is to create a view model with fields of each of the different model types you need and then pass them to partials as you need. For example:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
   public UserRole Role { get; set; }

   public List<ManageUsersInRole> UsersInRole { get; set; }

}
```

Then in your parent view you reference the `UserViewModel` and pass `UsersInRole` to the partial view. Example:

```
@model UserViewModel

<form method="post" action="/HKRole/AddUserToRole">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Role.Id" name="roleId" class="form-control" hidden />

    </div>
</form>
@Html.Partial("ManageUsersInRole", Model.UsersInRole);
```